# Port desktop to web application (bioinformatic)

Tags: python, web-applications, bioinformatics, blast

I want to port a few bioinformatic programs which I wrote for Windows OS to web applications. I'm using a few bioinformatic packages like BLAST, Bowtie or Primer3. These external tools usually take a file which the user provides, processes it and creates an output file which I parse and display. In addition these tools are using specific databases, which are created and reused by the user.

Up to now I was saving the databases created by the tools (the file is also provided by the user) and the output results on the PC where my software is installed. Now, I do not know how to handle such a setup on a web server. I cannot save all the databases created by the users from all over the world, but at the same time it is quite nasty to create a database again every time (e.g. the human genome db is 2.7 GB and takes some time to create it) when the user comes back (I guess one user creates about 5-10 databases per tool; I have 3 tools: 1 MB - 50 GB).

How can this problem be solved with web apps?

**Edit**
To make things more clear, I want actually only to know whether there is a more sophisticated way to reuse data which the user creates. I was thinking about to store those files temporally for a session. There is no possibility to ask for charging because those tools are quite specific and I don't have many users. In addition most users are close colleagues. After years fighting with different OS, debugging and maintaining my programs, I finally give up (I do this in my private time), it is simply to time consuming (in addition I have some request for Linux, Android and IOS).

Thanks

Comment: Charge them for it. You have to assume zero access to their PC unless you use tools like Flex. Also, it's not really fair to use up that much space with a web app. (And at that point it's not really a web app, as much as a desktop app with a browser UI).

Comment: The idea is to host it at our institutes severs. If I charge for the tools, I think nobody will use them and the work was for nothing...

Comment: Ok, so why don't you allow the user to upload their file to your server, do all the processing server side (requiring minimal changes to your program), and when it's done send it back. Instead of dropping and creating the database each time, use a single database and have tables for the custom data overrides on a per user basis.  I'm not sure how true this is, but I've read that a very small portion of the human genome is *actually* unique on a per-person basis. You *could* store a diff between the user's genome and some "Standard" and then you'd be storing *much* less information.

Comment: I assume you're in academia, and that the users are also in academia, hence why you don't want to charge? If you have users in industry, you can have different licencing agreements for them compared to academic researchers. It will help to know what you've done so far; you mentioned BLAST etc - do your tools *just* make a nice display for the output, or do any other processing? How integrated is it with the original programs - do they have to submit the output from those programs as input to yours?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the pipeline you are trying to build and the problem you are trying to resolve.  Are you trying to just reduce the amount of disk space your website uses?  Are you emulating [Galaxy](https://main.g2.bx.psu.edu/)?  Why not just provide the SQL dump to users as Christopher Pfohl recommended?  Have you heard of [BioStar](http://www.biostars.org/)?

Comment: cross posted on biostars: http://www.biostars.org/p/59138

Comment: What's wrong with the answers you got on biostars ? http://www.biostars.org/p/59138/ ?

You can implement the whole process using a private galaxy server: https://main.g2.bx.psu.edu/

Comment: @Pierre At Biostar I asked for advice for a framework. Here my question was how to handle such data, or is there a more clever way then to create everytime a DB again.

Comment: I don't want to use Galaxy because some of my tools have nothing to do with DNA sequences. In addition, I don't realy like the look and feel of Galaxy (what I quickly saw on their homepage). It might be nice if you do a lot of standard Blast's and NGS but I still want that my tools look like real aplications, not workflows.